# QTableWidget column resize

Tags: python, pyqt5

table is created in Qt Designer with settings:

[image]

In the main.py i just resized the columns:

```
self.table1.setColumnWidth(0, 150)
self.table1.setColumnWidth(1, 700)
```

If i run main.py i get:
[image]

My problem is: If i resize the window. I would like to keep the width of the Status column the same and only increase the width of the Description column. Has someone an idea how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You are resizing *all* columns manually, including the "Description" one, but I believe that what you want is to adapt that column automatically, so that it occupies as much space as possible, while keeping the other at the same width, right?

Comment: Correct. If grab with the mouse between Name and Description and move right. Name column should be bigger and the Description smaller. Status should be the same. If i grab the main window and move it to the right, name column and Status should be the same, only Description should get bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the [`setSectionResizeMode(index, mode)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-1) of the specific section of the horizontal header.

```py
    self.table1.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( 
        1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

Comment: If i do that, the column Description and column Status are the same size. If i resize the main window the size of each column gets bigger but the size is still the same.

Comment: Are you completely sure that you wrote **exactly** what I did, and you're also putting the "1" as first argument? Also, you should *not* use `self.table1.setColumnWidth(1, 700)` anymore, and uncheck the `horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection`

Comment: You are my hero :) Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that if an answer helped you to solve your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on its left.